# Lazy loading images - max x per second

Tags: javascript, html, lazy-loading

### Requirement

Load all images on a page with 100+ images in a manner that makes maximum x requests per second to avoid hitting a rate-limiter (which allows max X requests per second from the same IP).

### Potential Solution

Change the markup:

```
<img src="/someimage.jpg">
```

to

```
<img data-src="/someimage.jpg" class="lazyrate">
```

Implement a javascript that loads all images of class "lazyrate" up in an array, replaces data-src with src (which loads the image) one by one (or in batches of x), with a delay in between, which will not trigger the rate-limit.

Load 5 images, wait 1 second, load 5 next images, wait 1 second etc.

For improved user experience, combine this with only loading images that are visible (traditional lazy-loading)

### Question

Does something exist that already does this? Like a lazy-loading plugin which has a rate-limiting feature? Or is there another approach I should take?

### Background / "why don't you just..."

On an internal web-app for a large corporation with mandatory rate-limiting, a web app which displays a lot of images (100+ on a page), which sometimes trigger the rate-limiting, because all images are loaded at the same time.

- Splitting the images on multiple pages is not an option
- Disabling the rate limiter is not an option
- Offloading the images to a CDN or another domain is not an option because of auth requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up writing a simple jquery plugin to handle this, and it is shared here on github.

https://github.com/kjlibsol/lazyrate

It does not care about whether an image is on screen or not, because for my use-case it is nice to have, not need to have.

For future reference, here is the entire sourcecode:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.lazyRate = function (options) {

        var settings = $.extend({
            delay: 200 //default (in ms)
        }, options);

        var sleepValue = 0;

        return this.each(function () {
            var realSrc = $(this).data("src"); //the value of the real image, we want to display
            var id = this.id; //the id of the image - needed to use setTimeout (which does not understand "this")
            setTimeout(
                function () {
                    $("#" + id).attr("src", realSrc); //replace the src with the value from data-src (to load the image)
                }, sleepValue);
            sleepValue = sleepValue + settings.delay; //increase the delay for each loop, as the setTimeout returns right away
        });
    };

}(jQuery));
```

### Usage:

Put some data-src attributes with the real image in there - and add a src with a placeholder image

```
<img id="img001" data-src="img/IMG_0032.jpg" src="img/placeholder.png" height="200" class="lazyrate">
<img id="img002" data-src="img/IMG_0037.jpg" src="img/placeholder.png" height="200" class="lazyrate">
...
```

Now run the plugin on the class added - lazyrate in this case:

```
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".lazyrate").lazyRate();
        });
    </script>
```

[image]